# Navbar div decreases height vertically when minimized vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make a page responsive vertically. Whenever I decrease the size of the window vertically everything gets misplaced. How to prevent it?

Comment: You need to show your code, and present your issue in more detail. Please provide as much effort as you can, and you'll likely get more effort put into your answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a media query in your css for min-height or max-height. For example:

```
@media (min-height: 680px) {
  /*classes for this breakpoint*/
}
```